# Configure SSL in NGINX and Gunicorn in Django

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I'm new to deploying applications. I have a requirement of hosting a Django application using NGINX and Gunicorn.

I was able to successfully run the Django application using NGINX and Gunicorn. Now I have to configure the NGINX with HTTPS.

I went through a few of the posts on configuring SSL with NGINX and Gunicorn. But still not able to configure HTTPS for my application.

Below is the NGINX configuration file

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name domain_name;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/https_certificate.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/https_key.key;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
}

location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias PROJECT_STATIC_FILES_DIR;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
    alias PATH_TO_FAVICON/favicon.ico;
}
}
```

I've restarted the NGINX services but still, my web application shows it as HTTP. But not HTTPS. Can anyone please tell where I'm making the mistake.

Kindly excuse, if it is a repeated question.

Comment: Can you access your site on `https`? What happens when you hit `https://example.com` ?

Comment: @n1rna when I access through https its giving connection is not secure

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    # other directives
}
```

OR

You can create two server blocks. Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain_name;

    return 301 https://domain_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name domain_name;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/https_certificate.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/https_key.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        send_timeout 300;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


      }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias PROJECT_STATIC_FILES_DIR;
      }

   location = /favicon.ico {
      alias PATH_TO_FAVICON/favicon.ico;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Will try and let you know!

Comment: I have updated location block, could you please try with this? Also after updating try in incognito window.

Comment: I updated the location block with the mentioned configuration and tried in an incognito window now I'm getting "domain_name redirected you too many times." in the browser. :(

Comment: Saroj Rai could you please help me?

Comment: Edited, Could you please try this? Try to clear the cache

Comment: I'm not sure, looks like certificate is invalid. I'll just double check and try. Will keep you posted. Thank you.

Comment: Saroj Rai, my apologies. Since the certificate was invalid it was showing not secure. My initial configuration actually worked. Thank you for your time in helping me.